# Twofish MDS multiplication

Tags: matrix-multiplication, twofish, mds

I wasted the last 2 days finding literature and/or some illustrative explanations on how to perform correct multiplications against the MDS-Matrix in Twofish over $\operatorname{GF}(256)$ with $x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + 1$.

There seems to be no method - all algorithms I found are using pre-computed MDS tables, which isn't helping me understand it at all.

Could someone provide me with a simple and easy-to-use algorithm for this multiplication?

Comment: Have you looked at section 4.2 of the [Twofish paper](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-twofish-paper.pdf)? It would be helpful if you mentioned which part you are having trouble with. You need to know how to do 3 things: 1. Add in $GF(2^8)$ 2. multiply in $GF(2^8)$, and matrix multiplication (requires 1 and 2).

Answer (score 1):

Each byte act as a polynomial in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$

You will multiply the elements of the matrix in (Galois Field) $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ and add them in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$

[here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/laws/FFM.html) is a link where you can find a wonderful explanation for $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$